# Is double hashing collision resistant?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Double hashing can surely provide more security than only one layer of hashing but does that necessarily mean it is more collision resistant? This question in a more mathematical form: If $H$ is a collision resistant hash function, is $H\circ H\colon\;x\mapsto H(H(x))$ still collision resistant?

Comment: What specific threat do you expect to mitigate by hashing twice?

Answer (score 13):

Yes. Let $H$ be a collision resistant hash function and assume that one can find a collision $(x,y)$ for $H\circ H$, that is, $x$ and $y$ with $x\neq y$ and $H(H(x))=H(H(y))$.
Consider the results $H(x)$ and $H(y)$ of applying $H$ once to both inputs. Then either

- $H(x)=H(y)$, hence $(x,y)$ is a collision for $H$; or
- $H(x)\neq H(y)$, hence $(H(x),H(y))$ is a collision for $H$.

Therefore, obtaining a collision for $H\circ H$ allows an attacker to derive a collision for $H$, showing the claim.

---

What *could* suffer is the *output distribution* of $H\circ H$ as opposed to $H$, that is, even if $H$ is uniformly distributed on the set of all bit strings $\{0,1\}^\ast$, the distribution of $H\circ H$ may be arbitrarily bad. For instance, when $H$ is not bijective on its image (which is the usual case), there are always hash values that are not in $H\circ H$'s image while others may have lots of preimages. However, this doesn't break collision resistance in the cryptographic sense, as outlined above.

Comment: Hi. About the **collision probability**, $P_c[H]$, in optimal hashes (eg. SHA1), it increases with double hash?  That is, $P_c[H\circ H] > P_c[H]$ ?

Comment: If you preefer to comment as an other question, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/58542/42893